# How to open the vscode default file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings

I know there is such a file, now the new version is not, are the Settings window, I want the previous configuration file, how to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, press the shortcut key in vscode`cmd +shift + p`,

Then enter`Open Raw Default Settings`,

You will see the full file and hover over the file name to see the path.

Comment: Okay, I added it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to reset the configuration file ?

You can open your user settings with the command palette:

Press <kbd>F1</kbd>
Type `user settings`

From there delete the file's contents and save to reset your settings.

Let me know if that's work

Comment: This is not the answer I want, you are talking about user Settings, I want to include the system default Settings of all items file.

Comment: The link you send with Default settings is the user settings